# How do I count the most common entry in a table using sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I've got a race entry table with loads of different members in it. I want to find out the member that has been in the most races so far. How do I go about doing this please? I am using Oracle through SQL Developer so `TOP 1` does not work.

Comment: What version of oracle? Can you post your table structure, some sample data and then the desired result?

Comment: I am not quite sure what version oracle we are using as i am using the sql developer on my university sytem. The race entry has member_no which references a member table ive got. a member can appear multiples times in different races. I want to do an sql statement that finds out the member that has been in the most races so basically the memberno that appears most in the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most efficient way to do this does not use windows/analytic functions:

```
select member_no, TotalEntries
from (select member_no, count(*) TotalEntries, rownum as seqnum
      from yourtable
      group by member_no 
      order by 2 desc
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient approach would generally be to use analytic functions

```
SELECT member_no,
       cnt
  FROM (SELECT member_no, 
               count(*) cnt,
               rank() over (order by count(*) desc) rnk
          FROM race
         GROUP BY member_no)
 WHERE rnk = 1
```

You could also do a `GROUP BY/ HAVING` query but that would involve hitting the `race` table twice which would generally be less efficient.

What do you want to happen in the event of a tie?  As written, the query I posted will return multiple rows if there are multiple `member_no` values that are tied for the most entries in the `race` table.  If you want to arbitrarily pick one `member_no` value, you could use the `row_number` analytic function rather than `rank`.  Or you could add some additional criteria to the `order by` clause to ensure that there is a unique order to break the tie.

Answer (score 1):

Well you should be able to apply the `count()` aggregate and `group by member_no` to get the totals:

```
select member_no, count(*) TotalEntries
from yourtable
group by member_no 
order by TotalEntries desc
```

Then if you want to limit the records you should be able to use:

```
select member_no, TotalEntries
from
(
    select member_no, count(*) TotalEntries, row_number() over(order by count(*) desc) rn
    from yourtable
    group by member_no 
) src
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Not quite what you are looking for... this query will error because rownum is not in the group by clause of the inner select

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
with
data as (
    -- Create some test data
    select distinct mod(rownum,20)+1 race_id, round(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1,5)) member_id 
    from dual
    connect by level <= 100
)
-- real query starts here
select *
from (
    select member_id, count(*) race_count
    from data
    group by member_id
    order by race_count desc
)
where rownum <= 1;
```

Note: this will only return one member, even if there were several tied for the most races.

Answer (score 0):

```
select member_id, races
  from (select member_id, count(*) races, rank() over (order by count(*) desc) rnk
          from your_table
         group by member_id)
 where rnk = 1;
```

will get all members who've been in the most races.